# @StreamListener not receiving message from kafka topic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

I am able to send and receive the message using code:

```
@EnableBinding(Processor.class)
public class KafkaStreamsConfiguration {
  @StreamListener(Processor.INPUT)
  @SendTo(Processor.OUTPUT)
  public String processMessage(String message) {
    System.out.println("message = " + message);
    return message.replaceAll("my", "your");
  }
}


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DirtiesContext
public class StreamApplicationIT {
private static String topicToPublish = "eventUpdateFromEventModel";

@BeforeClass
public static void setup() {
    System.setProperty("spring.kafka.bootstrap-servers", embeddedKafka.getBrokersAsString());
}

@Autowired
private KafkaMessageSender<String> kafkaMessageSenderToTestErrors;

@Autowired
private KafkaMessageSender<EventNotificationDto> kafkaMessageSender;

@ClassRule
public static KafkaEmbedded embeddedKafka = new KafkaEmbedded(1, true, topicToPublish);

@Autowired
private Processor pipe;

@Autowired
private MessageCollector messageCollector;


@Rule
public OutputCapture outputCapture = new OutputCapture();

@Test
public void working() {
    pipe.input()
            .send(MessageBuilder.withPayload("This is my message")
                    .build());

    Object payload = messageCollector.forChannel(pipe.output())
            .poll()
            .getPayload();

    assertEquals("This is your message", payload.toString());
}

@Test
public void non_working() {
    kafkaMessageSenderToTestErrors.send(topicToPublish, "This was my message");
    assertTrue(isMessageReceived("This was your message", 50));
}

private boolean isMessageReceived(final String msg, final int maxAttempt) {
    return IntStream.rangeClosed(0, maxAttempt)
            .peek(a -> {
                try {
                    TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.sleep(100);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    fail();
                }
            }).anyMatch(i -> outputCapture.toString().contains(msg));
}
```

}

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class KafkaMessageSender<T> {
    private final KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> kafkaTemplate;
    private final ObjectWriter objectWriter;

    public KafkaMessageSender(KafkaTemplate<String, byte[]> kafkaTemplate, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.kafkaTemplate = kafkaTemplate;
        this.objectWriter = objectMapper.writer();
    }

    public void send(String topicName, T payload) {
        try {
            kafkaTemplate.send(topicName, objectWriter.writeValueAsString(payload).getBytes());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            log.info("error converting object into byte array {}", payload.toString().substring(0, 50));
        }
        log.info("sent payload to topic='{}'", topicName);
    }
}
```

But when I send the message using kafkaTemplate to any topic, StreamListener doesn't receive the message.

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=test
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=eventUpdateFromEventModel
```

my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-kafka</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

    <!-- Spring boot version -->
    <spring.boot.version>1.5.7.RELEASE</spring.boot.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Edgware.SR3</spring-cloud.version>

<dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Comment: 1. You don’t show your `KafkaTemplate` usage. 2. You don’t show the version of Kafka you are using (at least That `starter-Stream-jafka`). 3. You don’t show what error happens with your use-case. Thanks for understanding, but hard to help with the current state of your question

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan I have just updated al the details

Comment: Thanks, I see. Do you really send to the `eventUpdateFromEventModel` topic from that `send()` method ?

Comment: yes @ArtemBilan, I am sending to `eventUpdateFromEventModel `. I have updated the test with working and non-working

Comment: Do you have some error there?

Comment: No, there is a log at the time of sending the message, and then there is no further log. My listener is receiving the message, but I removed the listener to avoid conflict just incase.

Comment: How does it work if you configure `spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.headerMode=raw` ?

Comment: @ArtemBilan I tried adding `spring.cloud.stream.default.consumer.headerMode=raw` but same result!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> working

```
Object payload = messageCollector.forChannel(pipe.output())
        .poll()
        .getPayload();
```

...

> not working

```
KafkaTemplate
```

This is because you are using the TestBinder in your test, not the real Kafka broker and kafka binder.

The message collector is simply fetching it from the channel. If you want to test with a real Kafka broker, see the [test-embedded-kafka sample app](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/testing-samples).

**EDIT**

I just tested the Ditmars (boot 1.5.x) version of the sample and it works fine...

[image: sample]

Comment: Hi @Gary I tried to test with real kafka, and kafkalistener is receiving the message correctly. Just StreamListener is not receiving the message.

Comment: I tried your sample code too but with no success. I can only see a difference that your spring boot version is 2, and mine is 1.5.7

Comment: The boot 1.5.x/Ditmars version is [here](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/Ditmars).

Comment: The sample works fine for me - did you remove the `spring-cloud-stream-test-support` from the classpath? (That's what switches to the test binder).

Comment: thanks, Gary, both the sample didn't work straight away on my project, but with few changes, it worked. I will add my complete solution separately in case if that helps someone else.

Comment: hi krmanish007, how do you work out the solution, i meet the same problem with you.